# What caused Groundhog Day?

Tags: groundhog-day

Was there any any explanation, either in canon or out of universe (e.g. interviews with the writers), as to why Bill Murray's character initially got stuck in the time loop?

Comment: Asked and answered here; http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/827/what-caused-and-ended-the-time-loop-in-groundhog-day

Comment: @Richard So what's the procedure for cross-stack duplicates? Migrate, then close?

Comment: @SQB - Just to annoy any passing mods, I've answered it.

Comment: @SQB It's on topic on both. As far as I've ever seen, cross-site dupes are only removed when it's the same user asking them, which this does not appear to be.

Comment: Magic Realism..

Comment: My answer is better than the movies:SE one ☺

Answer (score 37, accepted):

According to the film's writer, Danny Rubin, the original idea was to leave it completely unresolved.

> *One more question to solve: how did Phil get stuck in time? Was there
> a time machine? A gypsy curse? A celestial anomaly? A magic clock?*
>
> *Even thinking about these things it was obvious that they were
> interchangeable, uninteresting, and completely unrelated to what was
> exciting to me about the premise. **So I decided not to have any
> explanation at all.** What I liked most about this totally logical but
> somehow heretical idea was its existential flavor. The movie became so
> much more human and relatable since none of us knows exactly how we
> got stuck here either.*
>
> <sub><sup>[How I wrote the script for Groundhog Day in less than a week](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/films/2016/08/07/how-i-wrote-the-script-for-groundhog-day-in-less-than-a-week/)</sup></sub>

At the insistence of the studio, he then created a [second draft](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/groundhogday.pdf) of the script in which Phil was **cursed by his ex-girlfriend** as an explanation for the time loop.

> **CUT TO:**
>
> **INSERT : A THICK BOOK** The cover reads "101 Curses, Spells and
> Enchantments You Can Do at Home." A well-manicured feminine hand opens
> the book to a marked page .
>
> **INT. CHERRY STREET INN - NIGHT - SAME TIME :** Phil enters his room and
> drunkenly tosses his overcoat, scarf and gloves on the floor in a
> heap.
>
> **INT. STEPHANIE'S BEDROOM - NIGHT :** Stephanie Decastro, Phil ' s
> disaffected ex-lover, is sitting cross-legged on the floor with the
> book of curses open in front of her. Her hair is down, she's wearing a
> caftan with a Zodiac print, there are candles everywhere and other
> vaguely occult decorating touches.
>
> **INSERT :** Phil's business card is dropped into a dish. Then the Tarot
> card of the Hanged Man, a chicken bone, and a feather are placed on
> top of it .
>
> **PHIL :** He stands at the sink, looking at himself in the mirror, flexing
> his muscles.
>
> **STEPHANIE :** Reading from the book she mutters incantations in a secret
> language, then she sprinkles some powder on the plate, then a few
> drops of oil. Then she makes a few passes over it with her hands and,
> much to her surprise, the contents of the plate spontaneously combust.
>
> **PHIL :** As he crosses to the bed, he accidentally knocks over the
> suitcase stand, spilling his clothes out onto the floor.-25- He
> contemplates picking them up for a moment, decides to leave them
> there, and flops down on the bed. He lies there looking u up at the
> ceiling until the room starts to spin around, then he closes his eyes
> and quickly drops off to sleep, still fully clothed.
>
> **STEPHANIE :** To complete the spell, she picks up a broken wristwatch and
> drops it into the fire.
>
> **INSERT :** Phil's business card, the Hanged Man and the broken watch in
> flames. The watch crystal is cracked and the hands are frozen at 5:59

But after they trimmed her character from [later versions](http://screenplayexplorer.com/wp-content/scripts/Groundhog-Day.pdf) of the script (finally removing her entirely for the film), that plotline made no sense so they seem to have decided to return to leaving it as an un-resolved question.

---

Purely out of interest, it's also worth noting that in the earlier draft, the original spell kept Phil in the loop for **10,000 years**(ish) and that it was *Rita's kiss* that finally broke the curse.

> **Phil :** *You want to know what's really amazing? I've been waiting for you every day for ten thousand years. I dream of you every night
> of my life. You've been my constant weapon against total despair, and
> just knowing you exist has kept me alive. How's that?*

Comment: Interesting, the story kind of works better without the voodoo explanation, since that explanation makes the one a little less existential, and more weekend at bernies 2.

Comment: That would also be a strange move on Stephanie's part, since she'd be cursing herself and everyone else to live in the same day too (just without remembering it like Phil does).

Comment: This is one of those situations were an explanation would cheapen the real story: that Phil becomes a better person.

Comment: @MiloPrice not a curse if she doesn't know about it. She'd never realise